# Shmini Atzeres; praying without minyan; when to daven Musaf; alternative strategy?

Tags: minyan, musaf, geshem-tal-ruach, shmini-atzeres

[Kitzur Shulchan Oruch 19](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4297864/jewish/Chapter-19-Laws-Dealing-With-Additions-to-Shemoneh-Esrei.htm) directs

> During the winter we add mashiv haruach (Causer of the wind to blow)
> umorid hageshem (and the rain to fall) to the second berachah of
> Shemoneh Esrei. We begin (this addition) with the Musaf prayer of
> Shemini Atzeres. The shamash (sexton) announces before [Musaf:] Mashiv
> haruach umorid hageshem. If he did not announce it it is not said then
> at the silent Musaf prayer. **An ill person who prays at home
> privately, likewise the villagers who have no minyan, should wait with
> [their] Musaf prayers until the hour of which it is certain that the
> city synagogues have completed Musaf prayers, and then they, too, can
> pray Musaf and say mashiv haruach umorid hageshem.**

This case was relevant to me praying at home because of COVID. A colleague suggested an alternative to waiting “until the city synagogues have completed Musaf prayers”. He said that I should get my wife to bang on the table and announce “Mashiv haruach umorid hageshem” and then I could get on and daven Musaf.

Is there a source for his suggestion?

Comment: If this worked, why do you need your wife to announce it? Just everyone announce to themselves.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the system that the change must happen betzibbur (that's why we do it with musaf, etc.)? I don't understand this suggestion at all

Comment: Your colleague's suggestion is incorrect. Not only is a person required to wait until the tzibbur has said it, but in a community in which there is no minyon, one must wait until the tzibur (had there been a minyan) would have said it. This was announced by the vaad harabanim in Baltimore last Pesach.